# change the data type from double to character

Tags: r

I got an error message when replacing missing values in csv with 0.

I'd like to know the solution to resolve the error. Thank you in advance.

Error message:

```
Error:
! Assigned data `0` must be compatible with existing data.
ℹ Error occurred for column `serious`.
✖ Can't convert <double> to <character>.
```

Code in R:

```
library(spdep)
library(sf)
library(spatstat)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(DCluster)
library(splancs)
library(ggplot2)
needs::prioritize(magrittr)

covid19j <- readr::read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kaz-ogiwara/covid19/master/data/prefectures.csv")

covid19j_20200613 <- dplyr::filter(covid19j,
                                   year==2020,
                                   month==6,
                                   date==13)
covid19j_20200613$CODE <- 1:47

covid19j_20200613[is.na(covid19j_20200613)] <- 0
```

prefecture.csv (part of this file)

```
year,month,date,prefectureNameJ,prefectureNameE,testedPositive,peopleTested,hospitalized,serious,discharged,deaths,effectiveReproductionNumber
2020,6,13,北海道,Hokkaido,1163,17390.0,120.0,10,950.0,91,1.3
2020,6,13,青森県,Aomori,27,910.0,0.0,0,26.0,1,
2020,6,13,岩手県,Iwate,0,776.0,0.0,0,0.0,0,
2020,6,13,宮城県,Miyagi,88,3253.0,0.0,0,87.0,1,
2020,6,13,秋田県,Akita,16,962.0,0.0,0,16.0,0,
2020,6,13,山形県,Yamagata,69,2475.0,2.0,1,67.0,0,
2020,6,13,福島県,Fukushima,81,5554.0,2.0,0,79.0,0,
```

Add info:

iMac (macOS 12.0.1)，R version 4.2.0，Rstudio 2022.02.3 Build 492

Comment: Try `covid19j_20200613$serious <- as.numeric(covid19j_20200613$serious)`

Comment: Check the column types, `str(covid19j)` .  There's either some inconsistency in your csv or `read_csv()` didn't guess the types  correctly and (at least) `serious` ended up being char.